# Jacobian matrix of $f(\mathbf x) :=$ $\frac{\mathbf x}{\|\mathbf x\|} =$ $\left(\frac{x_1}{\|\mathbf x\|} .....\frac{x_n}{\|\mathbf x\|} \right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

The following question comes from an introductory course on Multivariable Calculus. I have attempted the question but am seeking a solution verification as my attempt seems to be a little too simplistic for it to be right - unless I'm mistaken.

**Question**

> Consider $f: \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{ 0 \} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that:  $$f(\mathbf x) := \frac{\mathbf x}{\|\mathbf x\|} = \left(\frac{x_1}{\|\mathbf x\|} ..... \frac{x_n}{\|\mathbf x\|} \right)$$ Find the Jacobian matrix of $f$.

In previous examples I have come across involving the magnitude of the input vector, they tend to use the composition of the magnitude squared with the square root function. This seems excessively complicated, however, I am sure there must be a reason for this.

**My Attempt**

To find the Jacobian, we need to compute the partial derivatives. This presents itself in two possible scenarios. We know that $\frac{\partial f_i(\mathbf x)}{\partial x_j} = $ $\frac{\partial }{\partial x_j} \left(\frac{x_i}{\|\mathbf x\|}\right) $.

1. If $i \neq j$, then this is constant in $x_j$ and so $\frac{\partial f_i(\mathbf x)}{\partial x_j} = 0$
2. If $i=j$, then $\frac{\partial f_i(\mathbf x)}{\partial x_j}= \frac{\partial f_i(\mathbf x)}{\partial x_i} = \frac{1}{\|\mathbf x\|}$

This now gives us all the entires for us to input into the Jacobian matrix.

---

Am I missing something here? This seems too simple - particularly as the methods that  described above from other example problems seems to be slightly more elaborate than this.

I would be grateful for any feedback.

Comment: $\|\mathbf x\|$ is constant only if $\mathbf x$ is fixed. Remember that$$\|\mathbf x\|=\sqrt{{x_1}^2+\cdots+{x_n}^2}$$

Comment: The denominator $||x||$ depends on all the variables, so you need to use the quotient rule to compute your derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in comments,

$$\|\mathbf x\| = \sqrt{{x_1}^2 + \cdots + {x_n}^2}$$

is function of $n$ variables $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, so the derivatives do not depend only on the numerator of $\frac{x_i}{\|\mathbf x\|}$.

When $i\neq j$,

$$\frac{\partial f_i(\mathbf x)}{\partial x_j} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \frac{x_i}{\|\mathbf x\|} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \frac{x_i}{\sqrt{{x_1}^2+\cdots+{x_j}^2+\cdots+{x_n}^2}} = -\frac{x_ix_j}{\|\mathbf x\|^3}$$

When $i=j$,

$$\frac{\partial f_i(\mathbf x)}{\partial x_j} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \frac{x_i}{\|\mathbf x\|} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \frac{x_i}{\sqrt{{x_1}^2+\cdots+{x_i}^2+\cdots+{x_n}^2}} = \frac1{\|\mathbf x\|} - \frac{{x_i}^2}{\|\mathbf x\|^3}$$